# NSSortDescriptor sorting by alpha numeric

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to sort results from a CoreData "table" of "Tracks" in a similar manner to iTunes. The problem is, "ASC" sort uses the first characters to sort so I end up with:

> 1. (I Can't Get No) Satisfaction
> 2. A Hard Days Night

I'd like The Stones to show up in the results with "I", basically ignorning anything ^A-Za-z0-9. I've tried a custom selector and comparator block but it just ignores it so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience you're better off having a `sortName` attribute that you generate on object creation. You can then use that key to sort your CoreData results in a much simpler and faster fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to sort manually after fetching the results:

```
[tracks sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *pattern = @"[^A-Za-z0-9]";
    NSRegularExpression *expr = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                            error:&error];

    NSString *title1 = [(Track *)obj1 title];
    NSString *title2 = [(Track *)obj2 title];

    NSString *title1Match = [expr stringByReplacingMatchesInString:title1
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [title1 length])
                                                      withTemplate:@""];
    NSString *title2Match = [expr stringByReplacingMatchesInString:title2
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [title2 length])
                                                      withTemplate:@""];

    return [title1Match compare:title2Match options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
```

I tried [\W] as the pattern as well but seemed like there was a huge performance hit.